problems updating label and selfmade progressbar (kivy programming)
I am currently developing a small GUI for a project at university. Basically the GUI is supposed to be able to display some info about a process, and have a progressbar.
For some reason the first sequence of methods works well - the text label gets updated, the progressbar works. However when I press the second button, no updates are shown on the screen anymore. When I debug the code, I can see, that all the updates are working in the background - just - for whatever reason, these updates are not shown on screen. Can anyone help me?
When pressing the start button I want to clear the progressbar and eventually update some textlabels. For debugging reasons I am currently only working on clearing the progressbar, since none of these tasks seem to work so far.
The homing sequence (from home_rebuilder until home_stop) works perfectly well. I don't understand, why after pressing start() nothing works anymore.
I inserted Debugging messages all over my code. These show that the code is working fine in the background, however my screen doesn't want to show these updates:
I have also started to make some global variables. This helps some, but doesn't solve all my issues with the code
#Queues
queues: SystemQueues = SystemQueues()
bilderkennung_to_gui = queues.gui_bilderkennung_rx
gui_to_bilderkennung = queues.gui_bilderkennung_tx
pathing_to_gui = queues.gui_pathing_rx
gui_to_pathing = queues.gui_pathing_tx

home_started = False
progress_count = 1

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
 
    #initialize variables
    self.time_started = False
    self.time_seconds = 0
    self.progress_started = False
    
    self.energy_started = False

    #Reset counter
    
    #Schedule Queue Handler
    Clock.schedule_interval(self.queue_handler, 1)

    """if GuiWindow.pathing is None:
        GuiWindow.pathing = PathingFactory.setup_pathing(self.queues)
    
        #initialize threads
        GuiWindow.pathing_thread = Process(target=self.pathing.run)
        GuiWindow.cube_detection_thread = Process(target=init_cube_detection, args=(self.queues, ))"""
    

def queue_handler(self, get_pathing):
    try:
        # check for object in pathing queue
        if not GuiWindow.pathing_to_gui.empty():
            get_pathing = GuiWindow.pathing_to_gui.get_nowait()
        else:
            get_pathing = None
        
        prev_get_pathing = None
        
        #Debug Logger entry, if Pathing-Queue updated
        if get_pathing == prev_get_pathing:
            pass
        else:
            prev_get_pathing = get_pathing
            Logger.info(f"Pathing to gui = {get_pathing}")
        
        # Check if object in cubedetector queue
        if not GuiWindow.bilderkennung_to_gui.empty():
            get_bildanalyse = GuiWindow.bilderkennung_to_gui.get_nowait()
        else:
            get_bildanalyse = None

        # Debug Logger entry, if CubeDetector Queue updated
        prev_get_bildanalyse = None
        if get_bildanalyse == prev_get_bildanalyse:
            pass
        else:
            prev_get_bildanalyse = get_bildanalyse
            Logger.info(f"Bildanalyse to gui = {get_bildanalyse}")
        
        if isinstance(get_pathing, Setup):
            self.home_update(get_pathing)
        elif isinstance(get_pathing, MeasureResults):
            self.energy_update(get_pathing)
        elif isinstance(get_pathing, Build) or isinstance(get_bildanalyse, Analyse):
            self.start_update(get_pathing, get_bildanalyse)
        elif isinstance(get_pathing, Reset):
            self.reset_update(get_pathing)
        elif isinstance(get_pathing, Emergency):
            self.emergency(get_pathing)
                
    except Empty:
        Logger.debug("Die Queue ist leer")
    except Exception as e:
        Logger.debug(f"Fehler aufgetreten {e}")

#automatic homing when starting 3drebuilder the first time
def home_rebuilder(self):
GuiWindow.home_started = True
Logger.info(f"Homing started {self.home_started}")
command = Setup("home")
GuiWindow.gui_to_pathing.put(command)
    Clock.schedule_once(self.fake_homing,1)

#Fake homing_answer
def fake_homing(self, dt):
    command = Setup(None, "ack")
    GuiWindow.pathing_to_gui.put(command)

    Clock.schedule_once(self.fake_homing_two, 9)

def fake_homing_two(self, dt):
    command = Setup(None, "done")
    GuiWindow.pathing_to_gui.put(command)

def home_update(self, get_pathing: Setup):
    Logger.info("Home_update called")
    if GuiWindow.home_started:
        if get_pathing.ans == "ack":
            self.update_progress_label("Bitte warten..")

            zeiten = [0.1, 1.5, 2.2, 3.9, 5.2, 6.7, 8, 9.4]
            for zeit in zeiten:
                Clock.schedule_once(self.update_progress_bar, zeit)
            
        elif get_pathing.ans == "done":
            self.update_progress_label("Gerät ist betriebsbereit.")
            Clock.schedule_once(self.update_progress_bar, 0)
            self.ids.start.disabled = False
            self.ids.reset.disabled = False
            self.home_stop()

def home_stop(self):
    if GuiWindow.home_started:
        GuiWindow.home_started = False
        Logger.info(f"Home started {GuiWindow.home_started}")

def update_progress_label(self, text):
    self.ids.progress_label.text = text
    Logger.info(f"Progress_Label zeigt: {self.ids.progress_label.text}")

def update_progress_bar(self, dt):
    Logger.info("Update Progressbar called")
    if GuiWindow.progress_count <= 9:
        cube_id = "p"+str(self.progress_count)
        cube = self.ids.get(cube_id, None)
        cube.status = "highlight"
        GuiWindow.progress_count +=1
    else:
        pass

def clear_progress_bar(self): #FDoesn't work smh..
    Logger.info("Clear Progressbar called")
    GuiWindow.progress_count = 1
    Logger.info(f"Progress count {GuiWindow.progress_count}")
    self.update_gui()
    for i in range(1,10):
        cube_id = "p"+str(i)
        cube = self.ids.get(cube_id, None)
        Logger.info(f"Cube status {cube.status}")
        if cube:
            Cube.on_status_change(self, cube, None)
        else:
            Logger.error("Cube nicht erkannt")
    self.update_gui()
    

#Start_Button pressed
def start(self):
    if not GuiWindow.home_started:
        #clear progressbar
        self.clear_progress_bar()

    else:
        Logger.info("Es laufen noch Hintergrundprozesse. Start wird zurückgestellt.")

    #Clock.schedule_once(self.start_zwei)
    #Clock.schedule_once(self.start_drei)
    #Clock.schedule_once(self.start_vier)


#is currently deactivated - but just to show what I would like to implement    
def start_zwei(self, dt):
    Logger.info("Start_zwei was called")
    #ask for measurements of current
    command = Control("start")
    GuiWindow.gui_to_pathing.put(command)
    GuiWindow.gui_to_bilderkennung.put(command)
    
    #Label update
    self.update_progress_label("Bildanalyse initialisieren")

This is what it should look like (--> picture from going through the "homing" sequence)
homing sequence
After pressing start: no clearing of progressbar - no update of labels (text, timer, measurements) when activated in the code
enter image description here
